# how to use glTranslatef,glScalef,glRotatef in openGL

Tags: c, opengl, coordinate-transformation

I just want something like this video : https://youtu.be/dGWtdYlryQQ
It shows how to use `glTranslate`, `glRotate`, `gluOrtho2d` in OpenGL ,but it's not guide me anything

In my case, I draw a diamond instead of triangle and here is my condition

condition :

1. when I press r or R on the keyboard the diamond will rotate clockwise
2. when I press t or T on the keyboard the diamond will move to the right side
3. when I press + on the keyboard the diamond will bigger

here is my code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float angle = 0;
float t,s=0.5,m=0;

void myinit(void){
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
}
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
        if(key==27)
        {
            exit(0);

        }else if(key == 82 || key == 114){
            angle-=0.1;

            glRotatef(angle,0,0,1);
            glutPostRedisplay();

        }else if(key == 84 || key == 116 )
        {
             t+=0.01;
             glTranslatef(t,0,0);
             glutPostRedisplay();
        }else if(key == 43){
                 s+=0.01;

               //  m-=0.1;
               //  glTranslatef(m,m,0.0);
                 glScalef(s,s,0);
                 glutPostRedisplay();
        }
        (void)(x);
        (void)(y);
}
void hut(void){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glVertex3f(0.5,0.4,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.42,0.5,0.0);    // GREEN
        glVertex3f(0.44,0.5,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.5,1.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.46,0.5,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.25,0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.57,0.5,0.0);
        glEnd();
    glFlush();

    glColor3f(1.5,1.0,0.0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glVertex3f(0.44,0.55,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.42,0.5,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.46,0.5,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.25,0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.48,0.55,0.0);
        glEnd();

    glColor3f(1.5,1.0,0.0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glVertex3f(0.48,0.55,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.46,0.5,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.50,0.5,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.25,0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.52,0.55,0.0);
        glEnd();

    glColor3f(1.5,1.0,0.0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glVertex3f(0.52,0.55,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.50,0.5,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.54,0.5,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.25,0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.56,0.55,0.0);
        glEnd();
    glColor3f(1.5,1.0,0.0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glVertex3f(0.56,0.55,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.54,0.5,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.57,0.5,0.0);
        glEnd();
    glFlush();

}
int main(int argc,char** argv){
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutCreateWindow("Polygon with viewport");
    myinit();
    glutDisplayFunc(hut);

    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

And here is my output : https://drive.google.com/file/d/14HHRiCbOHK9ZSZtDOqSl4GP4aSy7UQLh/view?usp=sharing
It it’s not similar to this https://youtu.be/dGWtdYlryQQ

Comment: And what issue you are facing with that code ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14HHRiCbOHK9ZSZtDOqSl4GP4aSy7UQLh/view?usp=sharing  << This is my output . it's not similar to the output of this video >>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_Ihh3tF5fk&list=WL&index=32

Comment: Warning: What you're learning is a super-old version of OpenGL [that has no practical use nowadays](https://kos.gd/posts/dont-use-old-opengl/), I recommend to learn [the current OpenGL](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/) or WebGL instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operations on the matrix stack are based on one another. The reference system of each operation is the current transformation.

See the documentation of [**`glTranslate`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuXZ0.png):

> `glTranslate` produces a translation by `x y z` . The current matrix (see `glMatrixMode`) is multiplied by this translation matrix, with the product replacing the current matrix, [...]

and see the documentation of [**`glRotate`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp8Cf.png):

> `glRotate` produces a rotation of angle degrees around the vector `x y z` . The current matrix (see `glMatrixMode`) is multiplied by a rotation matrix with the product replacing the current matrix.

This means that `glRotate` does a rotation around the origin of the current local system.

While `glRotatetf` followed by `glTranslatef` results in:

[image]

`glTranslatef` followed by `glRotatef` results in:

[image]

Since you object is displaced, you have to translate it in that way, that the rotation point is placed in the origin:

```
glTranslatef(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
```

Then you can rotate it:

```
glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

And move it back:

```
glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
```

Note, on the [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) stack you have to "push" this operations in the reverse order. Further you should use the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix stack. (See [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml).)

**Remove all the matrix operations from the function `keyboard`** and add the following to the function `hut`:

```
void hut(void)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(t, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glScalef(s, s, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);

    .....
```

Further, your object gets destroyed by the aspect ratio of the view. This can be fixed by taking care of the aspect ratio when setting up the projection matrix:

```
float w = 640.0f;
float h = 480.0f;
glOrtho(0.0,w/h,0.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now i can solve this problem with your guide

Comment: i have some question , why we must use only glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f); and then we use  glTranslatef(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f); , when i change it to other value it doesn't work

Comment: could i use glTranslatef(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f); first > rotate and then glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f); ?

Answer (score 1):

glRotate rotates about the origin (0,0). Given your projection matrix (that you set with glOrtho) the origin is initially at the lower left corner of your screen, unless you use glTranslate. Your diamond is not centered at the origin, but positioned somewhat away from it. What you need to do is change the vertex values in your *void hut(void)* method to make the diamond centered at 0,0. Then use glTranslate to move the render origin (and thus also the diamond) to where you want it, then use glRotate.

Comment: You should add that the center is in the lower left corner because of the used projection matrix. By default, the center is in the middle of the screen (NDC ranges from [-1, 1]).